# Is it possible to make my app open and run in a server? If yes, how?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web-applications, npm, server

I am using AngularJs to develop a tool for the company I work for. My issue is that unless the app is running on a server, it will not allow me to make use of things like routing or ng-include—it does not let me request resources from the same directory.

My goal is that, without having to be connected to the internet, the user can just open the html file for the tool using a browser and a server will be created.

I cannot ask for the user to use the command line to make a port listen to the app using things like the [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) in npm. It is assumed that they do not have the ability to do that.

Comment: you could make it an electron app http://electron.atom.io/

Comment: Most of the end users of the app will not have either `git` or `nodejs` installed on their computers. Is this going to be an issue? @rob

Comment: you should be able to build windows/osx installers so it wouldn't be a problem